# Casting NSSEt in an conditional statement

Tags: xcode, comparison, nsset

Why is this statement always true regardless if the object at index 0 is in the set or not?

smallestNumberSort is an NSMutableArray

smallestNumberSet is an NSSet

```
if ([smallestNumberSet containsObject:[NSSet setWithObject:[smallestSortComplete objectAtIndex:0]]] == NO)
         [outcome removeAllObjects];
```

Minimal Code Example

```
-(void)GoodCoordinates
{
   NSCountedSet *outcome   = [[NSCountedSet alloc] init]; //will contain 4 random plot point between -50 and +50
   NSMutableArray smallestSortComplete = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES];


   NSMutableArray smallestCoords = [NSMutableArray alloc] initwithObjects: 
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:7]
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:-14]
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:10]
      [NSNumber numberWithInt:-21],nil];

 BOOL (inBounds = NO)
   {   

     [smallestSortComplete removeAllObjects];
    smallestSortComplete = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[outcome allObjects]]; 
    [smallestSortComplete sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    
   
               
    if ([smallestCoords containsObject:[smallestSortComplete objectAtIndex:0]] == NO)
       [outcome removeAllObjects];
   else
      inBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mre] where `[smallestSortComplete objectAtIndex:0]` is in `smallestCoords`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's unnest the code:

```
id object = [smallestSortComplete objectAtIndex:0];
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObject:object];
if ([smallestNumberSet containsObject:set] == NO)
    [outcome removeAllObjects];
```

The newly created `set` object is not in `smallestNumberSet`. Test if `object` is in `smallestNumberSet`:

```
id object = [smallestSortComplete objectAtIndex:0];
if ([smallestNumberSet containsObject:object] == NO)
    [outcome removeAllObjects];
```

or

```
if ([smallestNumberSet containsObject:[smallestSortComplete objectAtIndex:0]] == NO)
    [outcome removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: Ran both tests after un-nesting the code and they both failed.  I am sure it is something staring me in the face but is driving me crazy.

Comment: @KevinMcFadden Post a [mre] in the question please.